# Java Threads - how to show when the thread is not sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a program that add all of the odd numbers from 0 to 100. This is done by making use of 3 threads that work concurrently. Each thread needs to sleep between 0 and 3000 milliseconds (works) and I need to display the output of each thread (works).

I now need to display an output that states "the thread is no longer sleeping" when the threads awake, and have no idea how to do that. Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   AddOddNumbers task1 = new AddOddNumbers();
   task1.start();         
   AddOddNumbers task2 = new AddOddNumbers();
   task2.start();        
   AddOddNumbers task3 = new AddOddNumbers();
   task3.start();        
}
```

Here is the other class which does the rest:

```
public class AddOddNumbers extends Thread {

public void run(){

         int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i +=2){
             try {
                 sum +=i;
                 Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 3000));;
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(AddOddNumbers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

    } System.out.println(" The sum is " + sum);

public class AddOddNumbers extends Thread {

public void run(){

         int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i +=2){
             try {
                 sum +=i;
                 Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 3000));;
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(AddOddNumbers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

    }System.out.println(" The sum is " + sum);
```

I need it to display something like this:

```
The sum is 2500
The sum is 2500
The sum is 2500
Thread number 3 is no longer sleeping
Thread number 1 is no longer sleeping
Thread number 1 is no longer sleeping
```

Comment: Just place an output after the `sleep`. As soon as it is printed, the Thread no longer sleeps.

Comment: Put it in a `finally` block that ends your existing`try` block. This will also catch cases where the sleep is interrupted.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a threadNumber property of AddOddNumbers like this

```
public class AddOddNumbers extends Thread {

     private int threadNumber;


     public AddOddNumbers(int threadNumber) {
          this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
     }
```

and modify your run method like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i +=2){
             try {
                 System.out.println("Thread number " + threadNumber + " is not sleeping");

                 sum +=i;
                 Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 3000));;
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(AddOddNumbers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
```